# File.getAbsoluteFile() return "/" in unix shell execution

Tags: java, unix, relative-path, launchd

I'm using File.getAbsoluteFile() in order to build a relative path to the resources folder.
While I'm executing the code within IDE - works great.
I've compiled a jar file, and executing it trough script within terminal - works great.

In both cases I'm getting correct relative path :
"/Users/ie54553/Desktop/MyProject/"

I've tried to execute the same script by using OSX launchd
the plist looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>net.nathangrigg.archive-tweets</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/ie54553/Desktop/MyProject/script.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>

    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/out.out</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/err.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The script is being executed , but the relative path I'm getting is : "/" and not "/Users/ie54553/Desktop/MyProject/" as it should to be ...

Any idea why it happens ?

Comment: Where is the code? What is the fileon which you're calling this method?

Comment: File f = new File("").getAbsoluteFile();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I used next way

```
new File(ClassName.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
```

I got a path in which the jar is being executed , and then some string's manipulations then it worked ...

No the most "elegant" way , but works :)